# Representing an experiment with two dices using matplotlib - wrong representation

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, histogram

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XvTmZ.jpg)Representing an experiment with two dices using matplotlib - wrong representation
I have two 6-sided dices; I would like to represent the results after 1000 experiments using a matplotlib histogram. I have two problems:

1. I wish the x axis would show all possible results from 1 to 12 , one by one; but I have only the even number in the axis
2. The histogram is empty toward the middle, where the result for 7 should be displayed.

   Coding:

   #Dices, from book Python Crash course 2nd ed.

   from random import randint

   class Dice():
   """Represent a dice, which can be rolled."""

   ```
    def __init__(self, sides):
        """Initialize the die."""
        self.sides = sides

    def roll_die(self):
        """Return a number between 1 and the number of sides."""
        return randint(1, self.sides)
   ```

   #Make a 6-sided die, and show the results of 1000 rolls.
   #dice d6a

   d6a = Dice(6)

   resultd6a = []

   for roll_num in range(1000):

   ```
    result = d6a.roll_die()

    resultd6a.append(result)
   ```

   #dice d6b

   d6b = Dice(6)

   resultd6b = []

   for roll_num in range(1000):

   ```
    result = d6b.roll_die()

    resultd6b.append(result)
   ```

   #add dices

   sum_list = [a + b for a, b in zip(resultd6a, resultd6b)]

   print("\n10000 rolls of 2 6-sided dies:")

   print(sum_list)

   #Matplotlib display

   %pylab inline

   import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

   plt.hist(sum_list, alpha = 1, color = 'blue', label = '6 sided dice', bins = 12)

   plt.axis([0, 12, 0, 200])

   plt.xlabel("dice number")

   plt.ylabel("repetitions")

   plt.legend(loc = 'best')

   plt.title("frequency of different dices")

   plt.show()

Comment: `plt.hist(..., bins=np.arange(1.5, 13))` because your values are discrete.

Comment: `plt.xticks(range(2,13))` to show a label at each individual bar.

Comment: Great and clear help JohanC, many thanks for helping me solve my first stackoverflow question! ;-)